# Save State across generic UDF Hive

Tags: hadoop, hive, user-defined-functions

I have scenario, where I will be passing row by row to hive UDF and need to perform some validation on each of the row.

These validation are performed using some per-defined metadata, which I will need to load from external resource.

My problem is that can I this metadata load in init only once and apply it to all rows. As loading, metadata each time for each row will degrade performance drastically.

Comment: How large is the metadata?

Comment: Metadata is pretty large and it can span upto GB's. As they are domain look up tables with millions of records.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless this metadata changes a lot, I think your best bet is to keep that metadata in HDFS. Read it in the constructor and then you won't have to read it except whenever a mapper starts up.

Comment: Yeah storing in HDFS makes sense, and load will be faster too. We have data in sql tables and was planning to invoke stored procs through UDF. I also found another method, you can create static variables or singleton class that can also get job done.